# React-Router V4 - Difference between <Match> and <Route>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

Can someone tell me the key difference between these components in react-router v4?

Answer (score 7):

`<Match />` and `<Route />` are the same. In the alpha version it's called Match and in the beta it's called Route. Please refer to the current documentation to see what is available:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/api